# Calling Windows API from Golang

Tags: go, winapi

There is a Windows API function I need to call from Golang:

INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager-getconnectivity

I've read through the docs here:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

But it's still not clear to me how I would call this API. How would I do it, and use the result to check for internet connectivity?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [How to use COM (Component Object Model) in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37781676/1889329).